# Is it possible to style a label with css based on the input elements "checked" status?

Tags: css, checkbox, css-selectors, checked

I have a number of [input type checkbox] with corresponding labels, for example:

```html
<div>
    <input id="idOne" type="checkbox" checked>
    <input id="idTwo"  type="checkbox">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="idTwo">One</label>
    <label for="idTwo">Two</label>
</div>
```

The label/input are connected with the [for] property. I need to style the lable based on the [checked]-status of the checkbox. Can this be done WITHOUT a combinator as the  structure makes using child/sibling combinators a poor choice.

Somthing along the lines of:

```
label[input:checked = "true"]{
color:pink;
}
```

Can this be done in a stable fashion with css or will I need to add/remove a classs with JS?

THX in advance :)

I have tried to write a selector that will target the label of a checked input element (type="checkbox").

Comment: Where's your HTML? Because the answers - and possible solutions - are going to depend on that structure; please: post your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code, and read the "*[ask]*" guidelines also.

Comment: somerthing like: 
<div>
<input id="idOne" type="checkbox" checked>
<input id="idTwo"  type="checkbox">
</div>
<div>
<label for="idTwo">One</label>
<label for="idTwo">Two</label>
</div>
</div>

Comment: That HTML is malformed; you have two closing `</div>` tags, and you also show no labels; please edit the snippet I added to your question (scroll down to the preview, and below the snippet preview there's a link that says "Edit the above snippet." Do that, post the correct representative HTML (and include any attempted CSS there too, in the CSS panel).

Comment: just a mistake - changed

Comment: Look into :has - though it does not yet apply to all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can apply CSS to the label on the input checked status.

```css
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    color: #ccc;
    font-style: italic;
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    color: #0964aa;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="idname" name="cb_name"> 
<label for="idname">CSS is Awesome</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the issue is, that the structure makes using child/sibling combinators impossible. I think the solution has to be based on something along label[for="input.className:checked"]